# Redirect requests to one of port in list nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm using supervisord to host pyramid application. Supervisord can spawn multiple processes. Since its an web application, each process should have its own port. But I'm using nginx for reverse proxying :80 requests to my app. 
Lets say if there are 30 processes running, there will be 30 ports of my application itself. I need to write in upstream all those url:port. Instead of writing 30 times, I want to make it a good design. Is there a shortcut for this ?

```
    upstream myapp-site {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080 ;
        server 127.0.0.1:8081 ;
        server 127.0.0.1:8082 ;
        server 127.0.0.1:8083 ;
    }
```

**Instead of above, i want something like**

```
    upstream myapp-site {
        server 127.0.0.1:[8080:8083] ;
    }
```

Comment: "Since its an web application, each process should have its own port." Are you sure about this? What makes you think so? Please elaborate on this..

Comment: In pyramid app, Before executing I should give specified port if i'm running multiple processes otherwise I'll get **address already in use (port in use)** error. This is because it tries to start with default port number but that will be used already.

Comment: What about using a application server like "uwsgi" or "gunicorn" with multiple workers and just one port? (How do you start / stop / watch your application at the moment?)